# display issue with crystal reports / vs2010 using asp.net viewer

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2010

Upgraded from VS2008 to VS2010, my crystal reports look the same when exported as PDF, but when viewed with the ASP.NET CrystalReportViewer, the formatting of the fields is missing.

Viewing the html source for the report shows that it's defining a bunch of styles that look like the ones used within the report, but they're never assigned to the fields. This is true of reports that were created with the older version, and with new reports created with 2010.

Any ideas on why and how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue.  Fields from the upgraded reports that had the CssClass field set would appear unformatted. Removing the CssClass fixed the formatting.